# NoSuchMessageException in Spring boot 2.0.1

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to implement internationalization in my website but keep getting this exception :

```
org.springframework.context.NoSuchMessageException: No message found under code 'nav_home' for locale 'en'
```

My resource bundle is located here :

```
src/main/resources/translations
```

[Project structure [imgur]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3fuN.png)

Here is my configuration file :

```
package com.spring.henallux.FlourishBlotts.configuration;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource;
import org.springframework.validation.DefaultMessageCodesResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.LocaleResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.InterceptorRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor;

import java.util.Locale;

@Configuration
public class MainConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Bean
    public DefaultMessageCodesResolver defaultMessageCodesResolver() {
        DefaultMessageCodesResolver defaultMessageCodesResolver = new DefaultMessageCodesResolver();
        return defaultMessageCodesResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public ResourceBundleMessageSource resourceBundleMessageSource() {
        ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        messageSource.setBasenames("translations/general", "translations/errors");
        messageSource.setUseCodeAsDefaultMessage(true);
        return messageSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
        CookieLocaleResolver resolver = new CookieLocaleResolver();
        resolver.setDefaultLocale(new Locale("en"));
        resolver.setCookieName("flourish-blotts_localeCookie");
        resolver.setCookieMaxAge(-1);
        return resolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        LocaleChangeInterceptor interceptor = new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
        interceptor.setParamName("locale");
        registry.addInterceptor(interceptor);
    }
}
```

My controller :

```
package com.spring.henallux.FlourishBlotts.controller;

import com.spring.henallux.FlourishBlotts.model.LoginForm;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.MessageSource;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import java.util.Locale;

@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/home")
public class HomeController {

    private final MessageSource messageSource;

    @Autowired
    public HomeController(MessageSource messageSource) {
        this.messageSource = messageSource;
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String home (Model model, Locale locale){
        model.addAttribute("title", messageSource.getMessage("nav_home", null, locale));
        model.addAttribute("path", "home");
        model.addAttribute("loginForm", new LoginForm());
        return "integrated:home";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String login (@ModelAttribute(value="loginForm") LoginForm form){
        //TODO log user here
        return "redirect:/home";
    }
}
```

And my general_en.properties file :

```
nav_home=Home
nav_books=All books
nav_about=About us
nav_account=Account
nav_cart=Cart
```

I've been searching for hours but cannot find anything that helps me
I've modifying my basenames in my configuration class by adding

```
-> classpath:
-> classpath*:
-> / before translations, with and without classpath(*)
```

I get the same error when using the fr locale.

I still get the same error when I try to access any message from template.jsp instead of HomeController.

Please help me stackoverflow, you're my only hope ;)

Comment: You are making things too complex. Remove your bean for the `MessageSource` and `DefaultMessageCodesResolver` and just put `spring.messages.basename=translations/general,translations/errors` in your `application.properties`. Spring Boot already provides you with a `MessageSource` just configure it appropriately (work with the framework, not around it ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I found my error.

In my configuration file, my ResourceBundleMessageSource bean wasn't named messageSource()

That's it --'